# How can I clear the Python pdb screen?

Tags: python, pdb

Let's say I write

```
(Pdb) p dir(object)
```

and, now my screen is taken up with a list of attributes. How can I clear this text while still in debug mode? Importantly, I don't want to lose my place in the code.

Comment: is that related with python special? I mean using gdb clear screen function, does that work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depends on your OS. If you're on windows this should work:

```
import os; os.system('cls')
```

If you're on GNU/Linux (I think in Mac OS too) this should do the trick:

```
import os; os.system('clear')
```

But, if you use bash as you shell interpreter, there is a handy keymap: `CTRL+l`

Comment: FWIW for future readers, I've started doing this: `import os; clear = lambda: os.system('clear')`.

Comment: @gwg : You can't use `clear` as a variable in `pdb`, because it's already a command in pdb [cl(ear)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-clear), also if you name it to something else say `clr`, it will work in your current `module`, but won't work when you step into another `module` or `package`. Since the variable was global only for that python file i.e, your `main` file where you defined the variable. So, using `import os; os.system('clear')` seems to be the best way.

Answer (score 4):

You could always `print('\n'*30)`

Comment: This leaves the input cursor at the bottom of the console, which may be undesirable.

Answer (score 4):

In your `~/.pdbrc` (which is initialized when you fire up pdb) you can add :

```
import os
def cls(): os.system('clear')
```

Then when you are in Pdb, you can type `cls()` to clear the screen without needing as many key strokes at the command line.